# Dumping database after migration using Prisma inside docker container and docker compose (Proper flow)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, prisma

I am building a nestjs application where I have used Prisma. I am trying to figure out docker workflow for it. You can see on the code below, Currently, I am first running MySQL container and after healthcheck I am running prisma migrate command from my backend. This process is correct if the volume is removed as it will run migration after the database is ready. But Later I also want to dump a SQL file(insert commands) to the MySQL container once tables are migrated. So here on the below code it runs the dump even before tables are migrated. Can anyone help me on how to dump only after table migration has been created.

```
mysql:
platform: linux/x86_64
container_name: mysql
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
image: mysql:5.7.36
restart: always
ports:
  - 3306:3306
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: #####
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
  - ./mysqldump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
  timeout: 20s
  retries: 10
networks:
  - pushboard
reverse-proxy:
image: nginx:1.22.1
container_name: web_server
depends_on:
  - backend
  - frontend
volumes:
  - ./reverse_proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ports:
  - 80:80
networks:
  - pushboard
backend:
build: ./api
container_name: api
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
depends_on:
  mysql:
    condition: service_healthy
networks:
  - pushboard
env_file:
  - ./api/.env
volumes:
  - ./api:/app
  - /app/node_modules
  - /app/prisma
stdin_open: true 
restart: "on-failure:2"
tty: true
command: sh -c "yarn prisma migrate dev --name init && yarn start:dev"
```

Comment: Which script is responsible for dumping SQL file? Is it start:dev script?

Comment: - ./mysqldump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d on volume will execute the dump even before tables have been migrated